# Trying to set several border-left properties on a button element when in focus but they don't display

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS and React to build out a menu component with buttons for each Menu Item.

I'm trying to set the button styles to show a purple left border whenever a button is in the `focus` state.

I've set the styling following the TailwindCSS docs but for some reason the UI is not responding. I've tested single properties and they all work but I can't get border specific properties to cooperate.

I have a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-with-tailwinds-drawer-forked-pmrgb3?file=/src/SettingsMenu.js) for demonstration

```
import React from "react";

const MenuItem = ({ feature, idx }) => {
  return (
    <div className="ml-6 active:border-l-8 border-purple600" key={idx}>
      <button className="focus:outline-none focus:border-l-6 focus:border-violet-600">
        <h4 className="sticky top-0 text-black">{feature.featureCategory}</h4>
      </button>
      {feature.featureTypes.map((x, idx) => {
        return (
          <h6 className="pt-4 text-black ml-8" key={idx}>
            {x.featureType}
          </h6>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

Comment: Are the buttons dashboard, kanban etc?

Comment: Nope those are just filler buttons, the actual button I'm trying to style is in the MenuItem component

Comment: `border-l-6` isn't a class. use ` border-l-4` or `border-l-8`. To use `border-l-6`, extend the theme key in the `tailwind.config.js` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the code you're using.

- The TailWind package you're pulling in, via a CDN, is heavily out of date.
- 6 isn't a default option for border widths in TailWind therefore won't be available via CDN.

Ensure you're using a more current version of TailWind. Then, either add 6 as an option for border width to your config file or add it as a generated style.

Example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/DcVZLcEvqr

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<button class="focus:outline-none focus:border-l-[6px] focus:border-violet-600">Example Button</button>
```